# Is this geometric cover NP-Complete and how can I prove it?

Tags: algorithm, np

I have the following problem which I believe to be NP-Complete but I would like to prove it to be so:

Given a set of M points on a plane where circles can be centered and a set of N points which need to be covered by the circles, find the minimum area circle cover for the points. That is, find the radii of the circles and the centers (chosen from the M points) such that all the N points are covered and the total area of the circles is minimized. A given point is covered if it is inside at least one circle in cover.

I have been looking through various geometric cover NP-Complete results but they all involve using polygons for cover.

Any ideas of a suitable problem that this can be reduced to?

Thanks in advance for any clues.

Comment: Did you find [this paper](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/pubs/pdf/carrots.pdf) already? I didn't read past the first paragraph but it definitely seems related.

Comment: No I had not seen it (I am am implementer who has lost touch with theoretical CS for some time). Thanks for the pointer. I will read the paper.

Comment: If the circles overlap then does ​ "total area of the circles" ​ mean ​ "sum of the areas of the circles" ​ or ​ "area of the [union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)) of the circles" ? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Area of the union of the circles.

Comment: In that case, it's not clear that your problem even has a computable solution, since I don't see how to prove that the following problem has a computable solution: ​ Given a finite set of finite sets of circles such that each center's coordinates are both integers and each radius is the square-root of an integer, choose one of those sets-of-cricles such that the area of its union is minimized. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: The radii are not constrained to be integers. The center coordinates could be integers (I don't think this results in a loss of generality). By union I meant the projected area (i.e. if one circle intersects another, that intersection area is not counted twice). It is possible that there is more than one solution. Is that what you mean by "not computable" ?

Comment: No. ​ I mean, there might be _no_ algorithm A such that [for all instances x of your problem, A(x) is a function from M to [the set of non-negative real numbers] such that [the N points are all in the union of the circles] and [the area of the union is minimized subject to the N points all being in that union]]. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: I can't see the reasoning for the non-computablity assertion. Couldn't you simply evaluate the area of the union of each set and pick the minimum?

Comment: (Remember, I'm _not_ claiming to know that there's no algorithm, I'm just saying I don't see any proof that there _is_ such an algorithm.) ​ ​ ​ What outputs are you imagining for ​ "evaluate the area ..." ? ​ ​ ​  If you're imagining that the outputs are representations of the inputs, then that's begging the question. ​ If you're imagining that the outputs are formulas, then what operations are you thinking of the formulas being allowed to involve? ​ ​ ​ My next comment is just for if you're thinking of the outputs as _approximations_. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: (This comment is just for if you're thinking of the outputs of ​ "evaluate the area" ​ as approximations.) ​ ​ ​ What do you imagine ​ "pick the minimum" ​ doing when for each accuracy level it has tried so far, the absolute value of the difference between the approximations has been less than the sum of the error bounds? ​ ​ ​ If it picks one at such a point, then it could be wrong. ​ If it just tries getting better approximations until that's not the case, then it might run forever, since the values being approximated might be equal. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​